# Pass command to running java process?

Tags: java

I have a Java process that I run. If I start the process via SSH and pass commands to it works fine, but if I then terminate the SSH session I lose "control" of the process. How can I regain "control" of that process? It's still running.

I know the process ID. Is this possible or must I restart the process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to start a screen.

Try typing `screen` at the prompt. (Install the program if you don't have it.)

Example run:

```
$ ssh yourserver
Password:

$ screen                         # start the screen
$ java -jar YourApp.jar
output...
more output...
<Ctrl-A D>                       # detach process for later reattach
$ exit                           # exit your ssh session
```

next day

```
$ ssh yourserver
Password:

$ screen -x                      # reattach process

$ java -jar YourApp.jar
output...
more output...                   # back to where we were yesterday.
```

Type `man screen` for more information.

Comment: I've been using screen, maybe you can help with the problem. I am trying to send a command to a detatched process, the manual says to use the -X operator but it doesn't seem to be working.

If my screen process ID is 123 and I want to send the command "reboot" to my process what would be the syntax?

screen -S 123 -X "reboot" doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mail-archive.com/hlds_linux@list.valvesoftware.com/msg35519.html

Comment: Aha! That works, thanks. I do have one more issue though. if I want to "emulate" me typing something in using -X how could I do that? This program responds to me typing "hello" but "hello" is an unrecognised command. is there a special character I use to emulate typing?

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU `screen` program.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reconnect the standard input / output of a process that has become disconnected like that.  This is not specific to Java apps.

To avoid getting into this situation, run your application using the `screen` utility or something similar.